# How to record ambient music with quality in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, html5-audio

I want to record music tracks using a microphone in a Colab notebook.
I have tested several methods, but they work fine for speech recording, not music tracks.

The following code saves a `.wav` file,

```
import IPython.display as ipd
from IPython.display import Javascript
from google.colab import output
from base64 import b64decode
from socket import socket

RECORD = """
const sleep  = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
const b2text = blob => new Promise(resolve => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = e => resolve(e.srcElement.result)
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
})
var record = time => new Promise(async resolve => {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
  chunks = []
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data)
  recorder.start()
  await sleep(time)
  recorder.onstop = async ()=>{
    blob = new Blob(chunks)
    text = await b2text(blob)
    resolve(text)
  }
  recorder.stop()
})
"""

def recordAudio(sec=5):
  display(Javascript(RECORD))
  s = output.eval_js('record(%d)' % (sec*1000))
  b = b64decode(s.split(',')[1])
  with open('audio.wav','wb') as f:
    f.write(b)
  return 'audio.wav'  # or webm ?

ipd.display(ipd.Audio('audio.wav'))
```

But the quality is too poor to process afterward and get good results, for example, classifying the music genre.

I have tried scripts with libraries `soundevice` and `pyAudio` but they does not work in Google Colab. These libraries seem to control the PC's hardware, but it is not possible using Colab.

Comment: Why are you using google colab?

Comment: @DeadSec Thank you for commenting. I intend for other people could use the code on their PCs, test it and change it. I would not like to ask them to install Anaconda or Python Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: You could always compile python. At least would be easier to integrate since mixing languages like you're doing is not ideal at all. Other thing you could do is let javascript handle the recording and saving of the file and then use pyhon to only display it. Maybe there is some data loss or compression during the passing from js to python that is causing the issue

Comment: @DeadSec I do not understand well, how to use the Python of Colab with a .py which instructions give error when trying to control the hardware of the PC with libraries as `pyAudio`. There is no local Python in the PC.

Comment: Well javascript and browsers dont get much performance from driver cuz they have the browser as middle man. When you use in your PC you can use the drivers more directly or even in some lower level cases interact with the directly. This is why Zoom prefers the app from the browser, you get way more performance from running directly in the kernel then having the browser as middle man.

Comment: The way it transfer information from driver -> browser -> javascript -> python might be causing issues regarding to quality since very step there is some sort of compression or data loss. Its like the telephone game, the last person never receives the first message perfectly.